# Gmap study: multi auto routes/direction with unlimited waypoints click by click

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Since years I use Gmap to draw bicycle tracks point by point and save it as GPX.
Now I wanted to use auto routing (like GPSies.com or some other). So I wrote this project study, which works. Before I integrate it in my full application I publish this here as thanks for many solutions I got from here,

Take it as quick & dirty example. My js knowledge is more basically. Finally I will embedded it into a vb based application.

However, remarks and code improvements are welcome.
Please let me know, if you discover mistakes.

Have fun, Reinhard

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Maps API and Multiple routes - clokey2k</title>
<!-- Style to put some height on the map -->
<style type="text/css">
    #map-canvas { height: 500px };
</style>
<!-- Load the Google Maps aPI -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.22"></script>
<!-- All of the script for multiple requests -->
<script type="text/javascript">


var map = null;
var geocoder = null;
var directionsService = null;
var info;
var marker;

function init() {

 // Some basic map setup (from the API docs)
 var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.94, 6.96),
  zoom: 13,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  streetViewControl: false,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };

 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
 info = document.getElementById('info');

 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

}

 //////// muliple autoroute multiple waypoints, multiple service //////////////
var routeService = "GOOGLE"  //or OSM_YOURS
var routeMode = "cycle"  //bicycle, foot, ,motorcar //Google = BICYCLING
var routeMarkers = [];  // for route legs/steps
var routeMarkersArray = []; //keep all routemarkers of differnt routes
var routeLinesArray = []; //keep all routeLines of differnt routes

var setRM = 0;

function setRouteMarker() {
 if (setRM == 0) {     //start a new route
  prop = document.getElementById("sRoute");
   prop.style.color = "red";
   prop.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  temp = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
   addMarker(event.latLng, true)});
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  map.setOptions({draggableCursor:'crosshair'});
  setRM = 1;
 } else {       //finish a route
  prop = document.getElementById("sRoute");
   prop.style.color = "black";
   prop.style.fontWeight = "normal";
  map.setOptions({draggableCursor: null});
  google.maps.event.removeListener(temp);
  routeMarkersArray.push(routeMarkers)
  routeMarkers = [];
  routeLinesArray.push(routeLines)
  routeLinesArray = [];
  var routeKM = 0;
  setRM = 0;
 }
}

var pinRed = {
    url: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png',
};
var pinYellow = {
    url: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_yellow.png',
};




// OSM YOURS DIRECTION Service//
function addMarker(latlng) {
 /*
 geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
   mTitle = results[1].formatted_address;
  } else {
   mTitle = latlng.toUrlValue(6);
  }
 });
 */
 mTitle = "wp: " + routeMarkers.length;
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latlng,
  icon: pinRed,
  map: map,
  //title: mTitle,  //latlng.toUrlValue(6),
  draggable: true
 })
 marker.uid = routeMarkers.length;
 addRouteMarkerListener();
 routeMarkers.push(marker);

 routeService = document.getElementById("rtService").value;
 routeMode    = document.getElementById("rtMode").value;
 if (routeMarkers.length > 1) {
  if (routeService == "OSM_YOURS") {calcYoursRoute()};
  if (routeService == "GOOGLE")    {calcGoogleRoute()};
 }
}

function addRouteMarkerListener() {
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(e) {
  uid = this.uid;
  console.log("wp:" + uid);
  if (uid > 0) {   //move route for middle and last marker
   console.log("Route1")
   moveRoute(uid -1);   // call sube for calc
   if (uid < routeMarkers.length - 1) {
    moveRoute(uid);
  }}

  //move route for first point
  if (uid == 0) {
   routeLine = routeLines[0];
   routeKM = routeKM - routeLine.km
   routeLine.setMap(null);
   if (routeService == "OSM_YOURS") {calcYoursRoute(1)};
   if (routeService == "GOOGLE")    {calcGoogleRoute(1)};

  }
 }); //< dragend
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function(e) {
  uid = this.uid;
  console.log("remove wp:" + uid);
  // first Marker (uid), del first route (uid)
  if (uid == 0) {
   routeMarkers[uid].setMap(null);
   routeMarkers.splice(uid, 1); //delete first element

   routeLine = routeLines[uid];
   routeKM = routeKM - routeLine.km
   routeLine.setMap(null);
   routeLines.splice(uid, 1);
   if (routeLines.length == 1) {
    routeLines = [];
    routeKM = 0;
    routeMarker.uid = 0;
    info.innerHTML = routeKM +" km / " +routeMarkers.length +" wpts";
   }else{
    routeLines.splice(uid -1, 1);
    renumber()
   }

  }
  // last marker (uid), del last route (uid - 1)
  if (uid == routeMarkers.length -1) {
   routeMarkers[uid].setMap(null);
   routeMarkers.splice(uid, 1); //delete first element

   routeLine = routeLines[uid-1];
   routeKM = routeKM - routeLine.km
   routeLine.setMap(null);
   if (routeLines.length == 1) {
    routeLines = [];
    routeKM = 0;
    info.innerHTML = routeKM +" km / " +routeMarkers.length +" wpts";
   }else{
    routeLines.splice(uid -1, 1);
   }
  }
  //  middle Marker (uid), del route before and after (uid - 1), calc new route
  if (uid > 0 && uid < routeMarkers.length -1) {
   routeMarkers[uid].setMap(null);
   routeMarkers.splice(uid, 1); //delete first element
    //entfernt nachfolgende Route
   console.log("Del nachfolgende Route: " +uid +" von gesamt Routen: " +routeLines.length)
   routeLine = routeLines[uid];
   routeKM = routeKM - routeLine.km
   routeLine.setMap(null);
   routeLines.splice(uid, 1);

   renumber();
   console.log("Del/Replace vorhergehende Route: " +(uid -1) +" von gesamt Routen: " +routeLines.length);
   routeLine = routeLines[uid -1];
   routeKM = routeKM - routeLine.km
   routeLine.setMap(null);

   console.log("calc neue Route: " + (uid-1));
   if (routeService == "OSM_YOURS") {calcYoursRoute(uid)};
   if (routeService == "GOOGLE")    {calcGoogleRoute(uid)};


  }

 }); //< rightclick
} //< end routeMarkerListener

function renumber() {

 console.log("renumber");
 for (i=0; i < routeMarkers.length; i++) {
  console.log("renumber Marker:" + i);
  routeMarkers[i].uid = i;
  routeMarkers[i].setTitle = "wp: " +i;

 }
 for (i=0; i < routeLines.length; i++) {
  console.log("renumber Lines: " + i);
  routeLine = routeLines[i]
  routeLines.uid = i;
 }
}

function moveRoute(uid) {  //sub for dragend routemarker
 console.log("Route2"); //routline after Marker
 routeLine = routeLines[uid];
 routeKM = routeKM - routeLine.km;
 routeLine.setMap(null);
 if (routeService == "OSM_YOURS") {calcYoursRoute(uid + 1)};
 if (routeService == "GOOGLE")    {calcGoogleRoute(uid +1)};

}

function wait(ms){   //not in use
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   var end = start;
   while(end < start + ms) {
     end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}

function calcYoursRoute(index) {

 str = 'http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/gosmore.php?format=kml&'
  + 'flat={startLat}&flon={startLon}&tlat={endLat}&tlon={endLon}&v={travelMode}&fast=1&layer=mapnik'

 if(typeof(index) == 'undefined') {
  index = "new";
  start = routeMarkers[routeMarkers.length - 2].getPosition().toUrlValue(6);;
  end =   routeMarkers[routeMarkers.length - 1].getPosition().toUrlValue(6);
 }else{
  start = routeMarkers[index - 1].getPosition().toUrlValue(6);
  end =   routeMarkers[index - 0].getPosition().toUrlValue(6);
 }

 s = start.split(",");
 e = end.split(",");
 startLat = s[0]; startLon = s[1];
 endLat = e[0]; endLon = e[1];
 //alert(endLon);
 str = str.replace("{startLat}", startLat);
 str = str.replace("{startLon}", startLon);
 str = str.replace("{endLat}", endLat);
 str = str.replace("{endLon}", endLon);
  // set travelMode //
 str = str.replace("{travelMode}", "bicycle"); //cycle = Standard
    if (routeMode == "drive") {str = str.replace("{travelMode}", "motorcar")};
    if (routeMode == "walk")  {str = str.replace("{travelMode}", "foot")};

 //console.log(str);
 data = httpGet(str);

 coord = data.split("<coordinates>")
 coord = coord[1].split("</coordinates>")
 coord = coord[0].trim();
  //console.log(coord);
 var path = [];
 var clines = coord.split("\n");
 for (i=0; i<clines.length; i++) {
   iArray = clines[i].split(",");
  lng = iArray[0];
  lat = iArray[1];

  point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
  path.push(point)
 }

 //<distance>21.452372</distance>
   //<traveltime>1228</traveltime>
  // Get distance (in KM)
 dist = data.split("<distance>")
 dist = dist[1].split("</distance>")
 dist = dist[0].trim() * 1;
 dist = dist.toFixed(3) * 1;
  //write the route
 writeRoute(path, dist, index);
}

function httpGet(theUrl)
{
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false); //asyncron = true doesn't work correct.
 xhttp.send();
 result = xhttp.responseText;
 info.innerHTML = result;
 return result;
 //Notes from:http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp
 //Using async=false is not recommended, but for a few small requests this can be ok.
 //Remember that the JavaScript will NOT continue to execute, until the server response is ready.
 //If the server is busy or slow, the application will hang or stop.
 //Note: When you use async=false, do NOT write an onreadystatechange function -
 // just put the code after the send() statement:
}



function calcGoogleRoute(index) {

 if(typeof(index) == 'undefined') {
  index = "new";
  var rStart = routeMarkers[routeMarkers.length - 2].getPosition();
  var rEnd   = routeMarkers[routeMarkers.length - 1].getPosition();
 } else {
  var rStart = routeMarkers[index - 1].getPosition();
  var rEnd   = routeMarkers[index - 0].getPosition();

 }
 request = {
  origin: rStart,
  destination: rEnd
 };

    if (routeMode == "cycle") {request.travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.BICYCLING};
    if (routeMode == "drive") {request.travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING};
    if (routeMode == "walk") {request.travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING};

 directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
 if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  path =  result.routes[0].overview_path
  var sumKM = 0;
  var sumTime = 0;
            var myroute = result.routes[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
   sumKM += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
          sumTime += myroute.legs[i].duration.value;
            }
  sumKM = sumKM / 1000;
  console.log("Route calculated, write the route")
  writeRoute(path, sumKM, index, sumTime)
 } else if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
  alert("Could not find a route between these points");
 } else {
  alert("Directions request failed");
 }
 });
}

var routeLine = null;
var routeLines = [];
var routeKM = 0;
var routeTime = 0;

function writeRoute(path, routekm, index, routetime) {
 console.log("Write Route: " + (index - 1));
 color ="grey"
 if (routeService == "GOOGLE") {color = 'blue'};
 if (routeService == "OSM_YOURS") {color = 'grey'};
 var polyOptions = {
  map: map,
  path: path,
  strokeColor: color,
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 3,
  editable: false
 };
 routeLine = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
 routeLine.km = routekm;
 routeLine.service = routeService;
 routeLine.mode = routeMode;
 routeLine.uid = routeLines.length;
 addRouteLineListener();
 if (index == "new") {
  console.log("new route:" + (routeLines.length));
  routeLines.push(routeLine);
 }else{
  console.log("replace route:" + (index -1));
  routeLine.uid = index -1;
  routeLines[index -1] = routeLine;

 }
 routeKM += routekm;
 routeTime += routetime;
    info.innerHTML = routeKM +" km / " +routeMarkers.length +" wpts / " +routeTime +" time";
}

var tempMarker = null;
function addRouteLineListener() {

 google.maps.event.addListener(routeLine, 'mouseover', function() {
  console.log("routeLine id = " +this.uid)
 });

 google.maps.event.addListener(routeLine, 'click', function(event) {
  //set temp marker and save route line id
  lid = this.uid
  latlng = event.latLng

  if (tempMarker) tempMarker.setMap(null);
  tempMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: latlng,
   icon: pinYellow,
   map: map,
   title: "Remove to insert Route",
   draggable: true
  })
  tempMarker.lid = lid;

  // set listener for temp marker
   // rightclick del tempmarker
  google.maps.event.addListener(tempMarker, 'rightclick', function() {
   tempMarker.setMap(null);
  })
    //dragend replace temmarker und calc inserted routes
  google.maps.event.addListener(tempMarker, 'dragend', function(e) {
   //replace marker
   lid = this.lid
   latlng = e.latLng
   if (tempMarker) tempMarker.setMap(null);
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    icon: pinRed,
    map: map,
    //title: mTitle,  //latlng.toUrlValue(6),
    draggable: true
   })
   marker.uid = lid +1;
   addRouteMarkerListener();
   routeMarkers.splice(lid +1,0,marker);
   renumber();
   // write first route
   routeLine = routeLines[lid];
   routeKM = routeKM - routeLine.km
   routeLine.setMap(null);

   routeService = document.getElementById("rtService").value;
   routeMode    = document.getElementById("rtMode").value;

   if (routeService == "OSM_YOURS") {calcYoursRoute(lid+1)};
   if (routeService == "GOOGLE")    {calcGoogleRoute(lid+1)};

   // write second route
   routeLines.splice(lid + 1, 0,routeLines[lid]); //insert new item
   renumber();
   if (routeService == "OSM_YOURS") {calcYoursRoute(lid +2)};
   if (routeService == "GOOGLE")    {calcGoogleRoute(lid +2)};
   console.log("routlines: " +routeLines.length);

  }) //> end temp marker dragend
 }); //> end routeline on click
} //> end routeline listener


function resetRoute() {
    for (var i in routeLines) {
  routeLines[i].setMap(null);
 }
 routeLines = [];

    for (var i in routeMarkers) {
      routeMarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    routeMarkers = [];
 routeKM = 0;
}


// Get the ball rolling and trigger our init() on 'load'
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

</script>
 </head>
  <body>
<!-- Somewhere in the DOM for the map to be rendered -->
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<TABLE style="width: 512px;">
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
     <TD style="text-align: center;"> Route Mode <SELECT id="rtMode">
   <OPTION value="cycle">Cycle</OPTION>
   <OPTION value="walk">Walk</OPTION>
   <OPTION value="drive">Drive</OPTION></SELECT></TD>
    <TD style="text-align: center;"> Route Service <SELECT id="rtService">
           <OPTION value="GOOGLE">Google</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="OSM_YOURS">OSM_Yours</OPTION></SELECT></TD>

 <INPUT type="button" id="sRoute" onclick=" setRouteMarker();" value="Start Route"   >
 <INPUT type="button" id="D" onclick="resetRoute()" value="Reset Route">
 Quick Guide: Press Start Route, click on map to set waypoints. Rightclick deletes, drag moves a waypoint. Click on route insert one.
 </TR></TBODY></TABLE>

<div id="info" >0 / 0 / 0</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This would be better posted as a question/answer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Will regard it next time, if I find the question/answer (example) button - or contact you before. Best regards, Reinhard