# How to attach custom marker to generated route(draggable)?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I´m using the DirectionsService to generate some routes, but i want to change the default letter markers that Google provides (A, B, C, ...) with some of my own. I was able to do this following this example: http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/map_example_direction_customicon.html
I removed the provided markers, obtained the coordinates of the steps an generated the new markers at those locations, so far so good.

My problem is that the route is draggable, so when the marker is dragged, the route must be dragged too, but cant´find a way to link-attack the marker to the route. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render the direction as polyline, then you can use as marker what you want. This example was for other targets and is for your request maybe a little bit big, but it shows how it can be done ([Gmap study: multi auto routes/direction with unlimited waypoints click by click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023443/gmap-study-multi-auto-routes-direction-with-unlimited-waypoints-click-by-click))