# I need to show a Polyline with set of points taken dynamically from the DB exactly snap to road

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a polyline consisting of a set of latitude and longitude values which is taken dynamically from DB, I need it to snap exactly to the road when drawing it.

```
   $("#btnClk")
        .button()
        .click(function (event) {
            //  event.preventDefault();
            var vanselect = document.getElementById("svanid").value;
            var vanftdt = document.getElementById("ResDt").value;
         if ((vanselect.trim() != "") && (vanftdt.trim() != "")) {
                $.post("VanRoute.aspx", {
                    vanno: vanselect,
                    vandt: vanftdt

                     }, function (data, status) {

                    alert("Request In process, Please wait.");
                    var first = data.split('~')[0];
                    var second = data.split('~')[1];
                     var vanlocj = JSON.parse(first);

                    var vanlocjson = JSON.parse(second);


                    for (var i = 0; i < vanlocjson.length; i++) {

                        var vanlat, vanlon = "";
                        vanlat = vanlocjson[i].LAT;
                        vanlon = vanlocjson[i].LON;
```

After this how can i go further forward to snap a polyline exactly to road

I have created polyline overlay in function initialise which will work on page load.

```
       function initialize() {
          var mapOptions = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.860472, 77.664017),
              zoom: 15,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };

          map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
         // directionRenderer.setMap(map1);
         // directionRenderer.setOptions({
          //    draggable: true
          //});

          poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
              strokeColor: '#0000ff',
              strokeOpacity: 1.0,
              strokeWeight: 3
          });
         poly.setMap(map1);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  });
```

Comment: ".. I need it to snap exactly to the road ..". So you have to work with direction service and set your points from db as waypoints. Many examples are already given here.

Comment: Hi, yes i have worked with direction service to snap exactly on road , but need to snap with infinite loop of points so how do overcome with the waypoints limitation?@Refran,@John M

Answer (score 1):

Here I gave an example how to overcome the waypoint limitation using direction service: [Gmap study: multi auto routes/direction with unlimited waypoints click by click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023443/gmap-study-multi-auto-routes-direction-with-unlimited-waypoints-click-by-click). That you may took as basic and change it to your needs.