# Google Maps API, direction with 500 waypoints

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I have array with about 500 waypoints(with lat, lng) which are extracted from gps route, and i want to show it on google map, but google maps cant create direction/route to look like gps route with more than 23 waypoints(with 23 waypoints i cant replicate that route on maps), is there any other service that can do that, or suggestion, because i need many waypoints to get indentical route? I tryed with ng-map with directions.html and cant replicate gps direction.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmh, if you get your points from a gps-device, it's normally called a track and would be viewed as polyline, where you can use thousands of points.

However, in this example ([Gmap study: multi auto routes/direction with unlimited waypoints click by click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023443/gmap-study-multi-auto-routes-direction-with-unlimited-waypoints-click-by-click)) I show. how you can handle much more then 500 waypoints using gmap ("2,500 free requests per day") and - if that is not enough - you can combine with (for example) OSM-Yours or any other service (like 
GraphHopper Directions API) you can find in the intranet.

Also a combination between using route services and drawing parts as track/polyline for not routing able ways would be an option.

If you search here for "multiple waypoint" you may find also some other solutions, br. Reinhard